# How to recognize name of sub-list within list entity?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I have a chatbot powered by Microsoft Bot Framework which is using LUIS service for natural language recognition. One of the supported use cases is to allow users to list their tickets. Since there can multiple different types of tickets, one of the feature requests is to support filtering of these tickets by their type, for example - *orders*, *incidents*, etc.

---

Within LUIS, I have created **list** entity called *ticketType* with sub-lists representing individual ticket types and their synonyms:
[image: Entity type list for ticket type]

---

Next up, I have created intent called *listTickets*, where I provided following sample utterances:
[image: Intent for listing tickets]

---

Finally, I have also created patterns for the *listTickets* intent to *strengthen* the recognition:
[image: Patterns for listing tickets]

---

Now, after training and testing out my model, everything works just fine. Well, almost... The *ticketType* entity is correctly recognized, but I have no way to distinguish between individual ticket types based on my sub-lists as seen in the test results here:
[image: Test results]

---

### Question

How do I correctly train my LUIS model and properly create *ticketType* entity, so that LUIS correctly recognizes also the sub-list? Something like `ticketType::order` and `ticketType::incident`?

I have also read about [entity roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-roles), however this does not seem to be suitable for my scenario, because:

- According to example it is more suitable in situations, when same entity is used multiple times in utterance and roles are used to differentiate between individual entities based on their positions.
- In theory I could use roles, but then I would have to train my *listTickets* intent with every possible sub-list combination to have everything correctly labeled. Would patterns still make sense in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you test this in Web Chat or whichever channel you will be using. I created a LUIS model based off of yours and, when run thru Web Chat, the information you are seeking is readily available.

In my test, I passed "Display my request" as an utterance to the bot in a previous step. As you can see, "request" is a synonym of "order" which is found in "ticketType" (following your design). I'm able to extract the specific entity from the `recognizerResult` as well as the normalized values (i.e "sublists").

Hope of help!

```js
const recognizerResult = await this.recognizer.recognize(stepContext.context);
let intent = await LuisRecognizer.topIntent( recognizerResult );

console.log('1', intent )
console.log('2', recognizerResult.entities );
console.log('3', recognizerResult.entities.ticketType );
console.log('4', recognizerResult.luisResult.entities );
```

```
1 listTicket
2 { '$instance': { ticketType: [ [Object] ] },
  ticketType: [ [ 'order' ] ] }
3 [ [ 'order' ] ]
4 [ { entity: 'request',
    type: 'ticketType',
    startIndex: 11,
    endIndex: 17,
    resolution: { values: [Array] } } ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Steven Kanberg, I have inspected raw JSON which LUIS recognition API returns and I am able to retrieve the name of synonyms group (order, incident, etc) from the `resolution` property of the entity, example:
```{
  "entity": "orders",
  "type": "ticketType",
  "startIndex": 8,
  "endIndex": 13,
  "resolution": {
 "values": [
   "order"
 ]
  },
  "role": ""
}```
I am marking your answer as accepted.